# jQuery.jsonp not invoking success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I'm using [this](http://jsonp.afeld.me/) jQuery plugin to make cross-domain requests to a website. Here's the relevant part of my program:

```
$.jsonp({
        url: "http://soniccenter.org/source/utilities/codebot.php",
        data: data, //data is defined
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('.output').html(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            $('.output').html("Failed to access TSC. Perhaps the website is down?");
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.loading').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

I can tell the request was successful via my browser's network recorder (200 response code and the text I expect to receive), but the `error` callback seems to run instead of the `success` callback because that's what shows up after `complete` is invoked.

Is this some kind of asynchronous/synchronous problem or...?

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: @JohnBoker In the `.output` division, I see "Failed to access TSC...." (as happens in the `error` callback) instead of the response from the website that I know executed without error (which should display when the `success` callback is invoked). There is no error showing in the console.

Comment: if using chrome, you should check the request on the requests tab to see what was actually returned from the server.

Comment: @JohnBoker I've done that. It's the text string `Class 11048 is Sonic Colors DS / Times / Starlight Carnival 1 (Sonic). mathfreak231 is in \x02\x03151st place\x03\x02 out of 19 on this chart with 1:08.86, saying "Nicely done.".`.

Comment: that doesnt look like a jsonp result. jsonp would have something like `callbackFn('your data here')`;

Comment: @JohnBoker EDIT: "jQuery(?) doesn't accept JSONP responses with strings passed, so raw responses are wrapped with {data: "..."}." ok, i get it now

Comment: I'm not sure, i've never used the jsonp plugin.  for the cross domain request to work jsonp is the only way i know.  Otherwise you'd have to have a proxy on your server that would download the response and serve it from your domain.

Comment: @JohnBoker it's on github pages ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ i'll try to find a proxy that works for me i suppose